# Long в качестве индекса массива

Tags: java

Есть фрагмент кода:

```
long i = 1;
long[] arr = new long[i*6];
```

При компиляции появляется вот такая ошибка:

> Type mismatch: can not convert long to int

Как можно это исправить?

P.S Тип переменной менять нельзя или предложите как можно хранить огромные числа.

Comment: уточните задачу, потому что индексы массива в java могут быть только `int`, а массив из `long` максимальной длины займет 16 гигабайт.

Comment: Согласен с выше написанным, есть вариант создать ArrayList<>(i*6). Тогда внутри листа сразу появится соответствующий массив с нужной длиной.

Comment: @zRrr, 64-битная программа (что, надо дополнить, что не на джаве?) вполне может иметь массив больше 16 гигабайт.

Comment: @AndriiTorzhkov, Внутри ArrayList-a все тот же массив с размерностью int. Любые стандартные коллекции содержат максимум Integer.MAX_VALUE "ячеек". В принципе, наверное теоретически можно было бы накидать больше элементов в LinkedList или что-то подобное, но думаю, там тоже отслеживается переполнение, т.к. счетчик элементов тоже int.

Comment: @Eliot Alderson уточните вопрос: вам нужно хранить огромные числа или огромное количество (т.е. больше 2147483647) огромных чисел?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что new long[int count] -- это как конструктор массивов. И он принимает int, который весит в памяти 4 байта. Long же весит 8.
Надо конвертировать свой long в int. Иначе никак.

```
    int[] x = new int[(int) yourLongVariable]
```

Костыль -- можно в строку, потом в число интов.

```
    long i = 300L;
    String str = Long.toString(i);
    int n = Integer.valueOf(str);
```

Или же сделать кастом, как все нормальные люди.

```
    long i = 300L;
    int n = Integer.valueOf((int) i);
```

Comment: Какие-то все способы дурацкие, кроме первого...

Comment: в любом из этих способов нельзя обратиться к индексу массива, больше максимального значения типа int. Автору вопроса нужно обращаться к индексам с максимальным значениям long, насколько я понял.

Comment: Нету смысла делать массивы заоблачных размеров. Во первых -- это гигабайты памяти, во вторых -- можно реализовать с помощью библиотек.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-we-use-long-type-as-index-of-an-array-in-java-Is-it-because-of-continuous-allocation-of-memory-blocks-to-an-array Вот статья вам в помощь.
Лично я не вижу никакого смысла хранить HUGE AMOUNT OF DATA в одном массиве. Легче разбить на подмассивы, или же списки или коллекции юзать.
В целом -- так делать не рекомендуется. Предлагаю установить тогда базу данных, и там хранить все, что вам надо. Там уж точно по long все айдишки. Ну и RAM останется для вашей любимой ОС :)